# How to find the indefinite integral of $ \sin(4x)$?

Tags: calculus

When it is $x^n$, I can find the indefinite integral no problem. However I am confused as to what I need to do with this certain question. I would appreciate any help given!

Find the indefinite integral of: $\sin4x$

Answer (score 2):

substitution $4x=t$ gives $$\int\sin(4x)dx=\int\sin t\cdot\frac{1}{4}dt=\frac{1}{4}(-\cos t)+c=-\frac{1}{4}\cos(4x)+c$$